# SparkR on Windows - Spark SQL is not built with Hive support

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, sparkr

I'm trying to use Spark localy in my machine and I was able to reproduce the tutorial at:

http://blog.sparkiq-labs.com/2015/07/26/installing-and-starting-sparkr-locally-on-windows-os-and-rstudio/

However, when I try to use Hive I get the following error:

> Error in value[3L] : Spark SQL is not built with Hive support

The code:

```
## Set Environment variables
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = 'F:/Spark_build')
# Set the library Path
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME'), 'R','lib'),.libPaths()))

# load  SparkR
library(SparkR)

sc <- sparkR.init()
sqlContext <- sparkRHive.init(sc)

sparkR.stop()
```

First I suspected that it was the pre-built version of Spark, then I tried to build my own using Maven, which took almost an hour:

```
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package.
```

However, the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just followed the tutorial's instructions, you simply do not have Hive installed (try `hive` from the command line)... I have found that this is a common point of confusion for Spark beginners: "pre-built for Hadoop" does not mean that it *needs* Hadoop, let alone that it includes Hadoop (it does not), and the same holds for Hive.

Comment: You are right...I gave up trying make this work on Windows. It took me some hours but it is working on my linux VM

Comment: Best choice you could make :-)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem but we could not simply move to linux. After a while we found this page [spark on windows](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html) and we came up with the following solution:

- Create a file named hive-site.xml and write in it:

  `<configuration>
        <property>
          <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
          <value>C:\tmp\hive</value>
          <description>Scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
        </property>
      </configuration>`
- Set the environment variable HADOOP_CONF_DIR to the hive-site.xml directory.
- Set the environment variable HADOOP_HOME as stated at [hadoop winutils](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems)
- Run `winutils.exe chmod -R 777 C:\tmp\hive`

This solved the problem on our windows machine where we can now run SparkR with hive support.